# Is it possible to turn a string of a function name to a UnityAction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So some context to this question...

I'm reading in function names from a database and then using c# Reflection to be able to invoke them. However What i want is to be able to get a UnityAction from a string.

This is what i want to accomplish...

```
UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddVoidPersistentListener(UnityEvent, UnityAction);
```

What i know is that UnityAction is a Delegate but i'm not sure how i can accomplish going from a string to a UnityAction...

What i have...

```
UnityAction actionTemp;
        UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddVoidPersistentListener(quest.questTrigger, actionTemp = new UnityAction(() => Q_UtilityManager.GetFunctionName<Q_OnTrigger>(str)));
```

GetFunctionName() is...

```
    public static MethodInfo GetFunctionName<T>(string _func)
{
    Type thisType = typeof(T);
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(_func);
    return theMethod;
}
```

Which leads to quite a big error that boils down to...

```
Could not register callback
```

any Help would be amazing.

Comment: where is the method that you want to use as the callback?

Comment: is just a public void with no params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to turn a string of a function name to a UnityAction?

**Yes**. You can do this with the `Delegate.CreateDelegate` function. You pass in the type of the delegate which is `UnityAction`, the target script instance which can just be `this` or any script instance, finally the function name to call.

Here is a simple function that converts string function name to `UnityAction`:

```
UnityAction stringFunctionToUnityAction(object target, string functionName)
{
    UnityAction action = (UnityAction)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(UnityAction), target, functionName);
    return action;
}
```

Usage:

```
private UnityAction unityAction;

void Start()
{
    unityAction = stringFunctionToUnityAction(this, "hello");
    unityAction.Invoke();
}

//Function to call
void hello()
{
    Debug.Log("Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `MethodInfo` so now you just need to create a delegate from it and for that you can use [CreateDelegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194376(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In this example, I am using `Action` not `UnityAction` because I do not have the Unity references. However, changing the type to `UnityAction` or any other delegate will be the same.

In this example I am hardcoding the method name to `Do` but it will work if you were to get it from db as well. Then I am creating an `Action` from it using reflection.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var actionNameFromDb = "Do"; // Get it from db or wherever
        var callback = (Action)GetFunctionName<Program>(actionNameFromDb).CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
        Action handler = callback;

        callback();
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void Do()
    {
        Console.Write("Do was called.");
    }
    public static MethodInfo GetFunctionName<T>(string _func)
    {
        Type thisType = typeof(T);
        MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(_func);
        return theMethod;
    }
}
```

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/El0XrP)